# Frozen string - Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have this code:

```
 settings[:base_name].gsub! /[\x00\/\\:\*\?\"<>\|]/, ''
```

When I run the script it throws an error:

```
gsub!': can't modify frozen String (RuntimeError)
```

I have changed the code to this:

```
 settings[:base_name] = settings[:base_name].gsub /[\x00\/\\:\*\?\"<>\|]/, ''
```

The code above works, but I don't like at all, is there a way to properly use gsub! in this case?

Comment: Define "properly"; frozen string is frozen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Apparently, the API providing the string has frozen it, which means any method that modifies it will fail. Because `gsub!` modifies the string it is called on, a frozen object can not use `gsub!`. However, the *variable* that contains a frozen object can still be set to a non-frozen object, which is why your second code snippet works.

The API probably froze the object because it is a constant string that all of the instances share, and so one instance shouldn't be able to ruin the string. But they do define a setter method, so you can set the value.

Comment: @PabloElices: Sure. Glad I could help. If the API was implemented differently, you could do it the way you want to, but it isn't. The thing you just have to remember is that while `!` methods modify the *object* they are called on, they don't manipulate the *variable*. Variables contain objects, objects get called methods on. The distinction is crucial.

Answer (score 5):

@pabloelices,

The issue is that the `String` object referenced by `settings[:base_name]` has been [frozen](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-freeze) and is now effectively immutable.  You can check this by:

```
settings[:base_name].frozen?  # => will return 'true'
```

You could clean up the code and intent somewhat by doing the following:

```
my_setting = settings[:base_name].dup   # Create a duplicate of the setting.
settings[:base_name]  = my_setting.gsub /[\x00\/\\:\*\?\"<>\|]/, ''
```

But the original `String` object will not allow `gsub!` to be invoked on it.